# Disabling TLSv1.0 in java8

Tags: java, security, ssl, java-8, tls1.2

I'm trying to disable TLSv1.0 in Java 8

I have included TLSv1.0 in the following line as follow in the JRE/lib/security/java.security

**jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH, TLSv1.0**

still, I'm getting the ciphers from the TLSv1.0 when I tested, but when I configured other versions like TLSv1.1, I was able to successfully remove the respective ciphers

What might be the issue for this ?

Is there is any way to remove a specific ciphers in JRE level?

Answer (score 7):

You can disable TLSv1 and whatever ciphers you want using command line args, like so:

```
java -Djava.security.properties=disabled_tlsv1.properties
```

The file `disabled_tlsv1.properties` has a list of ciphers to disable, and supports protocols as well, e.g. `TLSv1`. The rest of the ciphers I list below are deemed insecure for TLSv1.1.

This still leaves TLSv1.1 workable though, as some ciphers for it are still enabled. Note that you can also do this in the JRE itself, to affect the entire server if you prefer, as detailed in the question itself.

#### disabled_tlsv1.properties

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 768,TLSv1,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5,TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
```

A git repo showing this, and how to verify that TLSv1 is disabled [can be found here](https://github.com/bradparks/java_disable_tls)

Answer (score 7):

Replace TLSv1.0 with TLSv1:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH, TLSv1
```

How to test?

```
openssl s_client -connect ip:port -tls1
```

Comment: try to highlight the keywords and be clear with the format it will help to reach out your answer for others

Answer (score 5):

for the first part question I was able to disable TLSv1.0 by modifying the line as below(used TLSv1 instead of TLSv1.0)

**jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH, TLSv1**

but I still want to get to know, is there are any possibilities that I can disable an entire cipher suite in JRE level, for example, removing below 3 ciphers

```
>    RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
>      RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
>      RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
```

Answer (score 2):

You could force the client to use a specific protocol by setting the java option

```
-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
```

Or  if are looking for disabling a specific cipher you could try setting

```
jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, RSA keySize < 1024
```

in java.security file

Comment: Let's say I want to disable a cipher suite like below, is there is any way to do that ?
RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA

Comment: The prefix `jdk.certpath` indicates that this is used for validating certificate chains, not for TLS as asked

Comment: Using 
`-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2` 

doesn't seem to change anything on openjdk 11.