# How to enable TLS1.2 for tomcat webserver connections We are using tomcat 7.0.82

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat, tomcat7, server.xml

I have a tomcat webapp where the client is using TLS1.2 but a technical scan found the server is still using TLS1.0. I want to enable TLS1.2. We are using Java 7 and the connector snippet for the server.xml is as below,

```
   <Connector SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="100" clientAuth="true" disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="true" connectionTimeout="300000" 
            socket.soLingerOn="false" maxKeepAliveRequests="1000" maxThreads="50" port="2024" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS" 
            keystoreFile="/cert/fic_rest.jks" keystorePass="********" 
            truststoreFile="/cert/fic_rest.jks" server="UnIdentified" compression="on" compressionMinSize="2048" 
            noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata" compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/javascript,text/css"
    />
<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 2023 -->
<Connector port="2023" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="2022" />

    <Connector  acceptCount="100" clientAuth="false" disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="true" connectionTimeout="300000" 
            socket.soLingerOn="false" maxKeepAliveRequests="1000" maxThreads="50" port="2020" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" server="UnIdentified"
    />
```

Would changing `"sslProtocol="TLS"` to `"sslProtocol="TLSv1.2"` is all that is enough?
We are using tomcat 7.0.82

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enable TLS 1.2 only in apache-tomcat-9 and Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52857932/enable-tls-1-2-only-in-apache-tomcat-9-and-java-8)

Comment: Which version of Tomcat are you using? Since you are using a pre-8.5 configuration syntax, I would guess 8.0 ([unsupported](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-80-eol.html)) or 7.0 ([soon to be unsupported](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-70-eol.html)). That also may influence you security audit.

Comment: We are using tomcat 7.0.82

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sslProtocol` configuration protocol does next to nothing: it only specifies which `SSLContext` to use, but from the perspective of a server this does not restrict anything. Any version of `SSLContext` sets the default SSL server protocols to the entire list of supported protocols (cf. [source code](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/f4d80957e89a19a29bb9f9807d2a28351ed7f7df/src/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/SSLContextImpl.java#L739)).

Therefore you need to set `sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2"` (cf. [Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support)) to restrict the accepted protocol versions to only TLS 1.2. You can then test your configuration [using `curl`](https://superuser.com/questions/606598/specifying-minor-tls-version-when-using-curl).

However, if usage of TLS versions less then 1.2 is a security constraint for the whole system (cf. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41181696/11748454)) by adding the following line to `$JRE_HOME/lib/security/java.security`:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1
```

Warning: this will influence all TLS connections in Java, even those with old databases.

Comment: Piotr P. Karwasz Our objective it to convince the client that all TLS versions supported by the jdk is enabled just by setting, "sslProtocol="TLS. So does this mean "sslProtocol="TLSv1.2" has not impact? Also by using curl we are getting Connected to localhost (::1) port 2064 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* warning: ignoring value of ssl.verifyhost
* skipping SSL peer certificate verification
* SSL connection using TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA which doesnt not specify what is the protocol used.

Comment: `curl --verbose` tells you which version was selected, but check [the answer I linked to](https://superuser.com/questions/606598/specifying-minor-tls-version-when-using-curl) on how force `curl`  to use only a specific version. If you wish to accept all TLS versions `sslProtocol="TLSv1.2"` will work, but the default value should work too (I don't have JRE 7 to test on).