# Disabling TLSv1.0 for Jsch in android application

Tags: java, android, ssl

I know that it is possible to disable TLSv1.0 (or others) in Java using JVM parameters as mentioned in [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41181696/disabling-tlsv1-0-in-java8) or [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32466407/how-to-force-java-server-to-accept-only-tls-1-2-and-reject-tls-1-0-and-tls-1-1-c).
Is there any way to disable it in an android App?

I am using JSch to do ssh port forwarding but I don't want TLS Client Hello in TLSv1.0. JSch doesn't have any API for using TLSv1.2 only.
So I decided to disable TLSv1.0 application wide.

I already used this but no success.

```
System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
```

```
Security.getProviders()
SSLContext.getDefault().getSupportedSSLParameters().setAlgorithmConstraints(algo);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "disable"? If you are using OkHttp (or things layered on it, like Retrofit) for your app's HTTPS requests, you can [specify which TLS versions you wish to support](https://square.github.io/okhttp/features/https/).

Comment: Question edited

Comment: Jsch uses the SSH protocol, not TLS. I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Have you tried  System.setProperty("jdk.tls.client.protocols","TLSv1.2") ?